# Drop down user Authentication with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

So I have one html page that is suppose to be the log in page. All I have so far is a drop down menu, and a button that says log in.

I looked into other ways to get user authentication to work, but my question is:
how would it be possible to just simply use a drop down menu, select a user, and then press log in, and log in into that specific user.

I am looking into ng-route, angular's location services to redirect when I press the "log in" button.

```
<div class="login">

        <p>Welcome to the log-in page!</p>
        <!--This is where the user selects their username-->
        <select>
            <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Please select a name</option>
            <option value="1">userName1</option>
            <option value="2">userName2</option>
        </select>

        <br \>
        <br \>

        <!--This is the login button-->
        <button type="button" ng-click=""> Login </button>



    </div>
```

Edit:

I understand that my question or at least what I am trying to do seems vague, but I am just trying to follow a git-hub project where it states

"The login screen allows the user to select their name. No password is required. Clicking the Login button takes them to the another screen."

I am just doing this to learn front-end and make my first web-app.

Second edit:

https://github.com/archfirst/trader-desktop

This is the git hub project I picked up.

Comment: This is a bit too broad of a question. Selecting a data from a model and redirecting to a state is only one small part of the process. How is the user data stored in order to persist the auth between states. How are states determined to be restricted to logged in users? Ideally, you would want to think about this before starting any UI interactions. Sure, a drop down is possible, but it's not the ideal solution from a security and UX point of view, a password should be used since authentication is what your looking for.

Comment: Hey @zilj I understand I am just following a github project I found online, and it says that "The login screen allows the user to select their name. No password is required. Clicking the Login button takes them to the another screen."

I understand that it is broad, for any and all security purposes, of course a better user authentication would be better, I am just trying to learn front-end, I know the basics of Angular but this git hub project seems simple enough. Should I link the git hub project?

Comment: It would certainly help :) please

Comment: @zilj Okay sure, here is the link

https://github.com/archfirst/trader-desktop

Again, any help would be great, I am just trying to learn as much as I can :)

Comment: I see, so your trying to build an angular app that uses a node restful api. Got it. I think really since this project is an exercise and does not actually seem to have any focus on teaching user authentication, rather just to bypass it, 'Authentication' shouldn't really be the focus here. In which case @lakhassane has got you on the right track. You need to define states (I recommend angular-uirouter) and then follow lakhassane's answer.

Comment: @zilj What do you mean define states? Is there any sort of documentation or examples you can lead me to?

Comment: To be honest with you if your keen to learn angular correctly. An online course would do the trick. Im a big fan of Todd Motto's teaching style (google him). If your just looking to hit your node api perhaps a native javascript solution might suffice. Or something your more familiar with. Apologies its too broad a subject to dive into on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if I understand when your question but if you're just trying to redirect when the user click on "Log in", you can add a function on that ng-click directive like this

```
<button type="button" ng-click="Login()"> Login </button>
```

And in a controller you define the function to just redirect to the appropriate route. Something like this.

```
$scope.Login = function() {
    $state.go(HOME_STATE);
}
```

HOME_STATE being the state you defined on your route for the home after logging.

Comment: Though correct, this only demonstrates the native behaviour of ngClick and UIRouter.

Comment: Well I guess that's just what he might needed...and check more the documentation too.

Comment: Of course, it wasn't mean to invalidate your response, just to point out that the OP may need to rethink their question in order to get a clearer response

Comment: Oh :) I know lol it's ok. You're right at first view we do not understand much what he means.

Answer (score 0):

Download angular router as it's not part of angular and config it in angular like this

```
 angular.module('yourAwesomeApp',['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('login',{
     templateUrl: 'login.html',
    })
    })
 <a type="button" href="#login"> Login </a>
```